# JavaScript прервать setInterval не замораживая страницу

Tags: javascript

Есть ли удобный способ прервать setInterval на определенное время, не замораживая при этом страницу? Важно потом продолжить выполнение setInterval.

Comment: `clearInterval(timer);` и снова `timer = setInterval(...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как уже ответили в комментариях - можно снимать интервал, и заново выставлять. Это самый простой и разумный способ временно прервать его выполнение.

Но если необходимо ***приостановить*** интервал (чтобы впоследствии продолжить с времени последнего отсчета) - вот пример решения такой задачи:

```js
var itrEl = document.getElementById('iterations'),
    tfsEl = document.getElementById('time-from-start'),
    pauseBtn = document.getElementById('pause'),
    interval;
interval = new RAFInterval(() => {
  itrEl.textContent = +itrEl.textContent + 1;
}, 5000);
interval.ontick = t => tfsEl.textContent = (t / 1000).toFixed(2);

pauseBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (interval.togglePause())
    this.textContent = 'Продолжить';
  else
    this.textContent = 'Приостановить';
});
interval.start();

function RAFInterval(func, delay, run = false) {
  let rqst, tStart, tLast, tIter,
      paused = false;
  tStart = tLast = tIter = 0;
  this.delay  = delay;
  this.ontick = null;
  let fr = time => {
    tLast = time;
    if (!paused) {
      tIter = time - tStart;
      if (this.ontick)
        this.ontick(tIter);
      if (tIter > delay) {
        func();
        tStart = time;
      }
    }
    rqst = requestAnimationFrame(fr);
  };
  this.togglePause = () => {
    if (!(paused = !paused))
      tStart = tLast - tIter;
    return paused;
  };
  this.start = () => fr();
  this.stop  = () => cancelAnimationFrame(rqst);
  if (run)
    this.start();
}
```

```html
Выполнено итераций: <span id="iterations">0</span><br>
Отсчет задержки: <span id="time-from-start">0</span>c<br>
<br>
<button id="pause">Приостановить</button>
```

У `requestAnimationFrame` есть плюс: в тех ситуациях, когда классические таймеры "тормозят" из-за стремления браузера выжать максимум отзывчивости - он работает плавно. Конечно, его минимальная разрешающая способность ~15..20мс, но я еще не встречал задач где *реально* требовалась б**о**льшая точность :)